# Nginx/FPM/PHP all php files say 'File not found.'

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

i just installed nginx 1.1.13 and php 5.4.0 on a centos 5.8 final 64bit machine. Nginx and PHP/Fpm are running, and I can run php scripts via ssh command line, but in the browser I keep getting 'File not found.' errors on all my PHP files.

This is how I have my nginx.conf handle PHP scripts:

```
      location ~ \.php$
      {
              root                    /opt/nginx/html;
              fastcgi_pass            unix:/tmp/fpm.sock;
              fastcgi_index           index.php;
              fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME /opt/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
              include                 fastcgi_params;
      }
```

This is a direct copy/paste from my other servers, where it works fine with this setup (but they run older versions of php/fpm).

Why am I getting those errors?

Comment: Never mind, it's sorted. It was a silly permissions issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put "include fastcgi_params;" before all "fastcgi_param *" lines, "include fastcgi_params;" overrides all you "fastcgi_param *" lines (see nginx debug log):

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root                    /opt/nginx/html;
    fastcgi_pass            unix:/tmp/fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index           index.php;
    include                 fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME /opt/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Comment: Man, I've wasted 4 hours on it and your answer helped me.

Comment: I have tried to overcome this problem since yesterday. Your answer helped me very much! Thank you!!!

Comment: how do we do this without hardcoding the path ? $document_root vars seems to be not wokring ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.

What I did to solve this was to check the user running nginx, php-fpm and check their permissions for accessing the folder where the root is. It is be default 'www-data'.

but you can find out by using the `ps aux | grep php-fpm` and `ps aux | grep nginx` commands.

You have to make sure the folder is accessible to the user running these processes.

Comment: Thank you for the clue. I tried to host my projects deep inside my Dropbox directory, which had 700 permissions by default. Changing Dropbox permission to 755 solved the issue.

Comment: This was my problem as well. I was restarting `nginx` after adding `www-data` to the proper group, but forgot to restart `php8.1-fpm`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and for me it was a misconfigure/non-existing "root" directive in the nginx server config

Answer (score 1):

I use such configuration, wish it could help you. It works in OS X. As for me, @Xosofox 's answer worked. I mistyped the version of nginx 1.6.2 as 1.2.6, so that the root became a non-existing directory.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    root           /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.6.2/html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.6.2/html$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by changing user and group tho the current user:group in php-fpm.d/www.conf

By default the user and group is 'nginx', change this....

Hope this helps